# Colimit of a direct system of monomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories, limits-colimits

Let $\mathcal A$ be an abelian category, $\{X_i,f_{ij}\}_{i\leqslant j\in I}$ a direct system of $\mathcal A$ such that for any $i\leqslant j\in I$, $f_{ij}:X_i\to X_j$ is an monomorphism.

> Suppose the colimit of $\{X_i,f_{ij}\}$ exists, can we deduce that the structural morphisms $u_i:X_i\to \varinjlim X_i$ are monomorphisms?

What I know is that it holds when $\mathcal A$ has enough injective objects and $I=\mathbb N$.

Comment: By the way, I'm skeptical of the claim that this holds when $\mathcal{A}$ has enough injectives.  Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @EricWofsey No reference, but I think I can prove it. The core is using the fact that every partially ordered set is cofinal with a well-founded partially ordered set, and for the latter case, ultilize a recurrent construction.

Comment: I am not at all convinced you can do that when your partially ordered set is uncountable.  If you aren't using anything special about abelian categories and your argument would also prove that an inverse limit of a system of surjections of nonempty sets is nonempty, then there's something wrong with it (because this statement is not true).

Comment: @EricWofsey Well I'm pretty sure my first statement about cofinality is true. As for that recurrent construction, I worked it out for the totally ordered case. Now come to think of it maby there is more subtlety lying in the general case. Could you tell any counterexample about the inverse limit of a system of subjections?

Comment: It is not true even if $I$ is totally ordered (the naive argument for when $I$ is well-ordered breaks down at limit steps).  See the note I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: For a totally ordered inverse system of surjections whose limit is empty, let the index set be the ordinal $\omega_1$ and for $\alpha<\omega_1$ let $X_\alpha$ be the set of all bounded order-preserving injections $\alpha\to\mathbb{Q}$.  When $\alpha<\beta$ there is a restriction map $X_\beta\to X_\alpha$, which you can show is surjective.  But an element of the inverse limit would give an injection $\omega_1\to\mathbb{Q}$, which is impossible.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to say "bounded order-preserving injections $\alpha\to\mathbb{Q}$".  You can just take injections $\alpha\to\mathbb{N}$ whose image has infinite complement.  (The more complicated thing with order-preserving injections is useful for constructing a fancier example in which the sets in the system are countable.)

Comment: @EricWofsey You are right, now I get what's wrong with my construction. Thanks for your very illustrated examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not necessarily.  For instance, let $\mathcal{A}$ be the category of finite abelian groups and take the direct system $$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{2}{\to}\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{2}{\to}\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{2}{\to}\mathbb{Z}/16\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{2}{\to}\mathbb{Z}/32\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{2}{\to}\dots$$

Given a cocone from this diagram to a finite abelian group $A$, note that every element of $\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$ must map to an element of $A$ that is both $2^n$-torsion and infinitely divisible by $2$.  But in a finite abelian group, such an element must be $0$.  It follows that the trivial group $0$ is a colimit of this system in $\mathcal{A}$.

In fact, this is not even true assuming $\mathcal{A}$ has enough injectives.  For instance, take $\mathcal{A}=Ab^{op}$: there exists an inverse system of surjections of nontrivial abelian groups such that the inverse limit is trivial (see, for instance, Section 4 of https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/papers/unpub/emptylim.pdf).  Explicitly, to get such an inverse system, you can take an inverse system of surjections of nonempty sets indexed by $\omega_1$ with empty inverse limit, and apply the free abelian group functor.